# Caching strategy of parse.com

Tags: ios, caching, parse-platform

One of my application is using Parse.com as its backend service. There is one table called ***Product*** which is queried through cachePolicy as ***kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork***. The problem is the client side always got the cached data even after I modified some of the fields. The reason I don't always get data through network is that I'm trying to save data traffic as much as possible.

My question is if there is a way to expire the cache in server side so that I'll get new data in client side as soon as I modify the data?  Thanks (My only solution by far is to delete the client app and reinstall it.This obviously is not an ideal solution.)

Comment: Shouldn't the invalidation happen on the client?

Comment: I'm not very sure. Because in my case, the client side doesn't know the server is updated at all. (Of course I don't know how parse.com internally work).

Comment: I suggest you to ask this on parse forum as well. They will let you know better silution.

Comment: What you're asking for is essentially "push" functionality. @Wain provides a more traditional alternative.

Comment: The problem is parse.com forum seems to be closed. They suggested to ask question in Stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide some time limit on the cache validity, generally on the client, and either call `clearCachedResult` on the query instance or `clearAllCachedResults` on `PFQuery` when the limit is exceeded.

You could create a cloud function which returns a minimal amount of data and informs the app about changes so it can decide how / when / which caches to remove. For example, you pass a list of class names and last requested dates and the cloud function returns the names of classes which have new data since those dates.

Comment: I just found the **clearCachedResult** function too. Yes it solves the problem but it defeats the purpose of kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork.

Comment: Anyway I think client side time limitation could be the only choice.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm sure there used to be a `maxCacheAge` that you could set on a query, but can't see it in the docs now. Anyway, there is nothing to automatically invalidate from the server.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can set the maxCacheAge of the PFQuery object to change the time limitation. Thanks. I guess this is the only acceptable solution by far.